# What is recommended? tensorflow train_and_evaluate or estimator.train, estimator.evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I see that tensorflow train_and_evaluate works a bit different as compared the traditional tf.estimator train followed by evaluate.
train_and_evaluate creates multiple sessions based on the number of epochs while train only creates one session.
I was wondering what are the key differences between train_and_evaluate and train followed by evaluate.
Which one is recommended?.

Answer (score 0):

We're updating the train_and_evaluate. It will do a single train call. 
For now, if you're not doing distributed training, I would recommend using [InMemoryEvaluatorHook](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/estimator/python/estimator/hooks.py#L32) with `train`. `InMemoryEvaluatorHook` is a new feauture, we'll be more than happy to hear your feedback.